Connected noncompact smooth manifold admits a complete Riemannian metric
This is Problem 13-17 from John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds.
Let $M$ be a connected noncompact smooth manifold and let $g$ be a Riemannian metric on $M$. Prove that there exists a positive function $h\in C^\infty(M)$ such that the Riemannian metric $\tilde{g}=hg$ is complete. Use this to prove that every connected smooth manifold admits a complete Riemannian metric. [Hint: let $f:M \to \mathbb{R}$ be an exhaustion function, and show that $h$ can be chosen so that $f$ is bounded on $\tilde{g}-$bounded sets.]
The first part of the question gives the fact that every connected smooth manifold admits a complete Riemannian metric, since every connected smooth manifold admits a Riemannian metric.
But I am struggling to prove the first part. Following the hint, I know that there exists a smooth positive exhaustion function $f:M\to \mathbb{R}$. I considered $h(x)=f(x)^2$ because then we have $|\gamma'|_{\tilde{g}} = \sqrt{h(\gamma)}|\gamma'|_g = f(\gamma) |\gamma'|_g.$
Now assume $A$ is a $\tilde{g}$-bounded set so that for all $x,y \in A$, we have $d_{\tilde{g}}(x,y)\le K$ for some $K>0$. Then for any $x,y \in A$, we have a piecewise smooth curve segment $\gamma:[a,b]\to M$ such that $\gamma(a)=x, \gamma(b)=y$ and $\int_a^b f(\gamma(t))|\gamma'(t)|_g dt \le K+1.$
I cannot figure out how to progress from here. How can I show that $f$ is bounded? And how can I use this result to show that $hg$ is complete?
